# Adding a custom UIButton and action to a view in window app delegate (ios)

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate, uiwindow

I am working on a tab bar application which needs a global title bar with a setttings button attached. I have achieved adding an imageview to the main window, then a label, another image, and finally a button. However, I cannot get this button to fire an action. it is set up like this:

```
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchupInside];
```

Then the action defined like:

```
-(void)settings{
        NSLog(@"please do something");
}
```

However nothing happens, the image doesn't even change like it is being pressed. Can i not define buttons in the app delegate this way? is it because the target is not something that is control based? i tried different targets but i must not fully understand what setting a target is. thanks for any help.

P.S.- i tried setting up the method like so as well:

```
 -(void) settings:(id)sender{
 }
```

and calling it by replacing the action with @selector(settings:) to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, this should work. But I noticed you have a typo in `Touchup`. It should be `TouchUp`, with a capital U.

Comment: Wait, why are you not using a UIToolbar or the like for your title/button?  Manually building up images, labels, etc., sounds tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I forgot I changed the view behind the button to a UIImageView. I can't believe I didn't think of this before since this same issue cost me 2 hours the other day. When you have an imageView always remember to set this flag if you want stuff on it:

```
(someImageView).userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Hopefully I save someone an hour or two of needless headaches.

P.S. Thanks for the speedy comment !